# How to overwrite my currently running executable?

Tags: c++, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overwrite executable in C:\Program\MyProg on Windows Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427700/overwrite-executable-in-c-program-myprog-on-windows-vista)

I have an application written in C++. It is running. how can I make it overwrite its own exe file so that on next start up it would be a new exe?

Kind of like an automatic update?

Comment: Regardless, there isn't much point in re-opening it as there are already numerous duplicates covering both Windows and Linux

Comment: @PaulR: But closing as a duplicate will provide a pointer to those, which (IMO) is worthwhile.

Answer (score 4):

This is not done in practice. What is usually done is:

Original program:

1. Launch a small "updater" program
2. Terminate

Updater program:

1. Wait for original to terminate.
2. Move the original out of the way (e.g. rename to ".old").
3. Move the new version into place.
4. Launch the new version.
5. Terminate.

This is far, far safer, since you aren't blowing away the old version until the new one is in place.

Answer (score 0):

1. copy it.
2. overwrite the copy.
3. before the running prog exit, create a low priority process witch can use the copy to repleace the original. like "auto delete".

it's a solution, anyway. i hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

if you have control over the running process (it is your program and you can make it aware) you should be able to unlock it so it can be overwritten, if it isn't your best bet is to terminate and restart it as said above